# How to apply access control to parts of my Joomla 2.5 component's preferences?

Tags: joomla, acl, preferences

I am creating a MVC component in Joomla 2.5. I am using access control to restrict access to different backend views of this component. Each of these views have some option fields in the component's preferences (config.xml).

I know how to apply access control to restrict access to the preferences as a whole, but I am wondering if there is a possibility to apply different access control restrictions to some of the fields within the preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about the **Preferences** you add to your main view using:

```
JToolBarHelper::preferences('com_mycomponent', $height, $width, $alt, $path, $onClose);
```

Then **no**, there is nothing in the checks the access of a given field in `com_config`'s default view (`/administrator/components/com_config/views/component/tmpl/default.php`)

One possible solution would be to only present the *real* Preferences button to Super Users or those with equivalent permissions and then create a customised version for all other users that only presents the fields from the form they have permission to use.

Of course this means you'll have to manage those additional meta-permissions yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Those are indeed the preferences I'm talking about. I came up with the same work around myself, but don't really like the idea of recreating com_config. Still thinking if I could do something with that $path parameter and/or field groups.

Comment: For your version of Preferences you don't need to recreate the entire `com_config`, just load it's `model` to allow you to present the options you want in the way you want to.

Comment: I followed your advice to use com_config's model. The controller part still needed quite some effort. Tricky part was to merge the input data of the few allowed fields with all other field values before save, otherwise all unauthorised component params will get lost. Very nice and easily solved though by the following line: $data =  array_merge(JComponentHelper::getParams("my_component")->toArray(),$data). I now have a 'Config' view that only shows the fields with attribute access_group="xxx". Thanks for your help!